# Replication how to retain data on the subscriber - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, replication, rmo

We have a local database that retains data for 2 months. I'm replicating the local database to a cloud database using SQL Transactional replication.The idea is we want to save a year worth of data. I disabled the DELETE from being replicated, and this works great. However, if the replication for any reason got reinitialized or someone runs the snapshot agent again in the publisher, I will lose all the data in the cloud and get the current image of my local database! What can I do to stop this from happening from the subscriber side? Is there a way to make the subscriber or the cloud ignores all forms of DELETE or re-initialization, and just keep building up replicated data from the local database?

Comment: Merely running the snapshot agent only produces a new snapshot -- this will not, by default, cause existing subscriptions to reinitialize. In fact, you can add new articles to the publication without reinitializing, simply by adding them and then producing a new snapshot. (For non-cloud setups, at least, I have no experience with Azure.) So if you find things are getting reinitialized with snapshots, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: As to the general issue of reinitialization -- the cleanest way is probably to configure the articles to "keep the existing table and delete" on the publisher as the way to handle existing tables (as opposed to "do nothing" and "truncate"). Then, on the subscriber, you can either `DENY DELETE` (but it's generally tricky to get this to play nice with accounts with broad permissions) or create an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger that simply produces an error. Obviously these triggers need to be disabled for a legitimate reinitialization.

Comment: Can you please tell me what do you mean by "keep the existing table and delete"? Are you talking about Article Properties->Destination Object -> Action if name is in use ->Keep existing object unchanged? Someone somewhere mentioned that and I tried it. It doesn't delete data or tables on the subscriber, but you will end up having duplicated errors for ever. I tried to ignore that error from the publisher and it didn't work I get and error in the Bulk select. I think it's still a duplication error.

Comment: the error I get from the distributor agent is " the process could not bulk copy into table "tablename" "

Comment: Whoops, of course. Reinitialization will always want to copy data, even if you manage to skip the deleting. And it will try to bulk copy to initialize a table -- not giving it permission "prevents" reinitialization, at the cost of making replication impossible entirely because it never passes the initial stage. I'm afraid the only real solution is: don't ever reinitialize. Make it impossible to casually do this. If it does happen, accept that you will lose the data and plan accordingly (i.e., restoring backups, saving data in a secondary table, whatever).